# Why does my pygame code become painfully slow after a certain time? Is there a way to make it run faster?

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote a program to model a phenomenon called **diffusion limited aggregation**, using the random motion of squares in pygame. The idea is that there is a stem and every particle (square) that touches it sticks to it and becomes part of the stem.

The code seems to work, but after like 30 seconds to a minute it starts to slow down quite a bit. I cannot figure out why.

```
import pygame
import random


#changing the row number will change the size of the squares, and bassically the size of the invisible 'array'
width = 1000
rows = 500
d = width//rows
e = {}
squares = []
accreted = []


#note: all positions are noted in array-like notation (a matrix of dimensions rows x rows)

#to convert it back to normal notation, do (square.position[0] * d, square.position[1] * d)


class square:

    def __init__(self, position):

        self.position = (position)

#method to move a square in a random direction (no diagonal) (brownian motion)

    def move(self):
        a = random.randint(0, 3)
        if a == 0:
            new_posi = (self.position[0] + 1)
            new_posj = (self.position[1])
        elif a == 1:
            new_posi = (self.position[0] - 1)
            new_posj = (self.position[1])
        elif a == 2:
            new_posi = (self.position[0])
            new_posj = (self.position[1] + 1)
        else:
            new_posi = (self.position[0])
            new_posj = (self.position[1] - 1)

        if new_posj<0 or new_posi<0 or new_posi>rows or new_posj>rows:
            self.move()
        else:
            self.position = (new_posi, new_posj)
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), [new_posi * d,  new_posj * d, d, d])


def accrete(square):
    accreted.append(square)
    if square in squares:
        squares.remove(square)

def redrawWindow(win):
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), [stem.position[0] * d, stem.position[1] * d, d, d])
    for square in squares:
        square.move()

        # here we make it so that every square that touches the stem stops moving, then a square that touches this square stops moving, etc.

        for accret in accreted:
            if square.position[1] == accret.position[1]+1 and square.position[0] == accret.position[0]:
                accrete(square)
            elif square.position[1] == accret.position[1]-1 and square.position[0] == accret.position[0]:
                accrete(square)
            elif square.position[1] == accret.position[1] and square.position[0] == accret.position[0]+1:
                accrete(square)
            elif square.position[1] == accret.position[1] and square.position[0] == accret.position[0]-1:
                accrete(square)
    for accret in accreted:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), [accret.position[0] * d, accret.position[1] * d, d, d])
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    global win
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while True:
        # pygame.time.delay(5)
        # clock.tick(64)
        redrawWindow(win)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()


#by changing the range here, we change how many squares are created

for i in range(5000):
    e["accreted{0}".format(i)] = square((random.randint(0, rows), random.randint(0, rows)))
    squares.append(e["accreted{0}".format(i)])

 #a stem to start accretion from


stem = square((rows/2, rows/2))
accrete(stem)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've watched your simulation run for a while on my MacBook Pro.  It seems that on my system, it takes quite a bit longer than a minute...maybe more like 5 or so...before it starts to quite obviously slow down.  But it does nonetheless.

I think the problem is that you are building this "accreted" structure during your simulation, and due to this, the number of "accreted" squares (those stored in the `accreted` list) keeps increasing. For each iteration of your program, your code needs to compare the position of each live square against the position of each "accreted" square.  So over time, the number of comparisons you have to do continues to grow.

You likely need to find a way to optimize your algorithm if you want to be able to maintain the update speed (the frame rate) as the sim progresses.  You need to figure out how to be smarter about performing your comparisons to somehow avoid this geometric progression in iteration time that occurs as the structure you're building grows.

UPDATE AND POSSIBLE OPTIMIZATION: I see a pretty simple optimization that you could add to your code to greatly speed it up.  What you can do is maintain a bounding box around your "accreted" squares.  When you add a new square to that list, you increase the size of the bounding box, if necessary, so that it contains the new square.  Now, when you first check for a collision between a live square and an the list of accreted squares, you can first check for if the live square is within the bounding box of the accreted squares (with a little extra margin as appropriate) before testing for a collision between that square and any one accreted squares.  This would let you immediately rule out collisions between most of the live squares and the accreted squares with just one collision test for each live square.  This should have the effect of allowing your code to stay about as fast in later rounds as it is in the early rounds, since most of the live squares will always be trivially rejected as collision candidates regardless who big the accreted structure gets.

UPDATE 2: What I describe is definitely what's going on with your code.  I added a little code to count the number of collision tests you perform in each round of your sim.  Here's the number of tests being performed at one second intervals, along with how long one iteration of your sim is taking, in seconds:

```
0 5000 0.023629821000000106
1 9998 0.023406135000000106
2 24980 0.03102543400000002
...
30 99680 0.07482247300000111
31 99680 0.08382184299999551
...
59 114563 0.08984024400000123
60 114563 0.087317634999998
```

The first iteration of your code does 5000 hit tests, as expected, and a single iteration of your sim takes about .023 seconds.  After a minute, your sim is having to do more than 20 times as many tests per iteration, 114563, and now a single iteration is taking .087 seconds.  This problem just keeps growing, and your code just keeps slowing down. (It's interesting to note that most of the "progress" of your sim up to one minute has occurred in the first 30 seconds.  For this run, only 3 accretes occurred in the second 30 second interval.)

Comment: interesting, do you have any idea how to do the bounding box? i am unfortunately not a computer scientist but a geology student, so my knowledge in this field is quite limited

Comment: At the start of your sim, you'd create 4 vars, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax.  With each square you add to accreted, you'd make sure that the position of that square was within the bounds of these variables by updating as necessary.  When you test a square for a "hit", you first check to see if it falls in the area defined by these vars.  if not, then the square won't hit any of the accreted squares since they all fall within that area.

Answer (score 2):

The first and probably best optimization is to keep a list of "forbidden" squares that will trigger the freeze of a particle instead of iterating over all positions in `accreted` multiple times.

So e.g. when we start with the first stem particle (or square, or whatever you call it), we also store the positions above, beneath, left and right of that particle's position in a `set`. It's important to use a `set` because looking up items in a set is much, much faster that using a `list`.

After moving a square, we now check if that square's new position is in this set. If it is, we add all adjacent positions to that set, also.

The next thing we can improve is the list of squares itself. Instead of removing a freezed square from the list, we create a new list every frame and add all squares that are not freezed this turn. (Your code is actually buggy by not making a copy of the list of squares and iterating over that copy while removing items from the original list) I'll use a `deque` since adding to it is slightly faster that a regular list.

Another bottleneck is the huge amount of random numbers you create each frame. `random.randint()` becomes painfully slow. We could create a list of random numbers at the start of the script and use that so we don't have to create new random numbers while running.

We could also change the drawing. Using `pygame.draw.rect` 5000 times is also quite slow. Let's create a surface and blit it with pygame's new batch function `Surface.blits` (I guess using `pygame.surfarray` to manipulate the screen surface directly would be even faster).

In the code below I also implemented the bounding box suggested by CryptoFool, because why not, but the biggest speed up is using a set as I described above.

With these changes, I get ~200 FPS without any slowdown over time:

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
import random
from collections import deque

def get_rand_factory():
    length = 100000000
    sample = np.random.randint(1, 5, length).tolist()
    index = -1
    def inner():
        nonlocal index
        index += 1
        if index == length:
            index = 0
        return sample[index]
    return inner

get_rand = get_rand_factory()

def move(x, y, rows):
    dx, dy = x, y
    a = get_rand()
    if a == 1: dx += 1
    elif a == 2: dx -= 1
    elif a == 3: dy += 1
    else: dy -= 1

    if dx<0 or dy<0 or dx>rows or dy>rows:
        return move(x, y, rows)
    return dx, dy

def get_adjacent(x, y):
    for dx, dy in (1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1):
        yield x + dx, y + dy 

def get_bounds(positions):
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = 9999, 9999, 0, 0
    for x, y in positions:
        min_x = min(min_x, x)
        min_y = min(min_y, y)
        max_x = max(max_x, x)
        max_y = max(max_y, y)
    return min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y

def main():

    width = 1000
    rows = 500
    d = width//rows
    squares = deque()
    accreted = set()
    adjacent_accreted = set()

    win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, width))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    for i in range(5000):
        pos = (random.randint(0, rows), random.randint(0, rows))
        squares.append(pos)

    stem = (rows/2, rows/2)
    accreted.add(stem)
    adjacent_accreted.add(stem)
    for adj in get_adjacent(*stem):
        adjacent_accreted.add(adj)

    rect_white = pygame.Surface((d, d))
    rect_white.fill('white')

    rect_blue = pygame.Surface((d, d))
    rect_blue.fill((255, 0, 255))

    bounds = get_bounds(adjacent_accreted)
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = bounds

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        win.fill((0, 0, 0))

        new_state = deque()
        for x, y in squares:
            die = False
            new_pos = move(x, y, rows)

            if min_x <= new_pos[0] <= max_x and min_y <= new_pos[1] <= max_y:
                if new_pos in adjacent_accreted:
                    accreted.add(new_pos)
                    adjacent_accreted.add(new_pos)
                    for adj in get_adjacent(*new_pos):
                        adjacent_accreted.add(adj)
                    die = True
                    bounds = get_bounds(adjacent_accreted)
                    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = bounds     
            if not die:
                new_state.append(new_pos)
                
        squares = new_state

        win.blits(blit_sequence=((rect_blue, (pos[0]*d, pos[1]*d)) for pos in accreted))
        win.blits(blit_sequence=((rect_white, (pos[0]*d, pos[1]*d)) for pos in squares))

        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 255), [bounds[0] * d, bounds[1] * d, (bounds[2]-bounds[0]) * d, (bounds[3]-bounds[1]) * d], 1)
            
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.set_caption(f'{clock.get_fps():.2f} {len(squares)=} {len(accreted)=}')
        clock.tick()
 
main()
```

[image]

Comment: woah tanks a lot

Comment: Wow, amazing answer!  I was thinking of tinkering with it myself and had some of this going through my head.  But now I don't have to.  Great stuff!

Comment: Your line near the end of your code that calls `set_caption` is syntactically malformed, at least for my version of Python  I had to take it out to run your code.  Is that `=` some new function of f-strings?

Comment: @CryptoFool It was added in 3.8. If you add an `=` sign this way, the variable name will be included, e.g. `f'{len(squares)=}'` will result in the string `'len(squares)=4987'` instead of just `'4987'`. Quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your code:

```
def accrete(square):
    accreted.append(square)
    if square in squares:
        squares.remove(square)
```

squares is a list containing up to 5000 items. Searching for any content needs up to 5000 comparisons because there is no index and all items have to be checked until it is found in the list. Use a set instead if the entries are unique and the order does not care. A set in indexed and searching for an item runs very fast.